# Jquery hide() / show()

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Проблема с toggle эффектом.

По клику на ссылку, все открывается, но ссылка перестает быть активной и не реагирует на последующие нажатия. Другими словами, открывается, но не закрывается ...

**[Вот код.](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/dTBEa/1/)**

В чем может быть проблема, что я делаю не так?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас блок **nav** перекрывает кнопку. Решение элементарное - поставить кнопку слоем выше, например **z-index: 11;**, тогда [всё нормально работает](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/dTBEa/2/).

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо. Все на столько элементарно, а я ... эх.

Comment: @Astor, не вижу ничего страшного. В запарке, я тоже допускаю элементарные просчеты/ошибки, о которых даже кому-нибудь признаться стыдно. ))